# Apostrophe in codeblock

Tags: code, apostrophe

Hello I was trying to put '\n' on codeblock, and I have just realized that my apostrophe is in weird direction when in codeblock[image]

I wanted something like

[image]

The code was

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} 


\definecolor{blue-green}{rgb}{0.0, 0.87, 0.87}
\colorlet{mygray}{black!30}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!blue}
\colorlet{mymauve}{red!60!blue}

\lstset{
  mathescape,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},  
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breakatwhitespace=false,      
  breaklines=true,                
  captionpos=b,                    
  commentstyle=\color{mygreen}, 
  extendedchars=true,              
  frame=single,                   
  keepspaces=true,             
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      
  language=c++,                 
  numbers=none,                
  numbersep=5pt,                   
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{blue}, 
  rulecolor=\color{black},        
  showspaces=false,               
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                 
  stepnumber=5,                  
  stringstyle=\color{magenta}, 
% morecomment=[l][\color{red}]{\#},   
  tabsize=3,                      
  title=\lstname,  
  emph = {true,false},
  emphstyle = {\color{cyan}}, 
}

\begin{document}
test
\begin{lstlisting}
'\n'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(This is not just in codeblock but always like this. But I want to know how to use in codeblock.)

Comment: Just add `upquote=true` to the list of arguments of `\listset`. See section 4.3.6. of the user guide of the `listings` package for more information. Actually, the remark in that section that it's necessary to load the `textcomp` package is no longer correct; some years ago, if I recall correctly, much of the functionality of the `textcomp` package was folded into the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just noticed a (hopefully minor) typo in my earlier comment: the name of the command is `\lstset`, not `\listset`... I've looked up *when* `textcomp` was folded into the LaTeX kernel; it would appear to have occurred with the `2020/02/02` release.